# The organizational data vs the organization data

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

I am a bit confusing with 2 noun words are combined together because I've seen many phrases such as web data, car data, human resource, child care ... etc.

Here, instead of **the organizational data**, can I write **the organization data**? 
And if no, why?

Comment: Yes, you can.  But the organisational data is more common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two different structures.  One is a simple adjective-noun combination, the other is a [*compound* of two nouns](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-nouns/nouns-compound-nouns).  Similar compounds:

> board meeting
>
> shareholder equity
>
> management company

Both "organizational data" and "organization data" are fine, but as Khan mentions, *organizational data* *feels* more idiomatic.

Comment: Where'd your link go?